# MovieLens dataset - shell script

Tags: macos, shell

I am using the dataset and shell script found [here](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-10m-README.html). When I run the shell script with:

`sh split_ratings.sh`

The terminal reads:

```
ratings count: 
expr: syntax error
set size: 
expr: syntax error
remainder: 
tail: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
tail: -: No such file or directory
tail: -: No such file or directory
r1.test created.   lines.
r1.train created.   lines.
tail: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
tail: -: No such file or directory
tail: -: No such file or directory
r2.test created.   lines.
r2.train created.   lines.
tail: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
tail: -: No such file or directory
tail: -: No such file or directory
r3.test created.   lines.
r3.train created.   lines.
expr: syntax error
tail: -: No such file or directory
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
tail: -: No such file or directory
tail: -: No such file or directory
r4.test created.   lines.
r4.train created.   lines.
tail: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
head: -: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
tail: -: No such file or directory
tail: -: No such file or directory
r5.test created.   lines.
r5.train created.   lines.
ra.test created.   lines.

ra.train created.   lines.
rb.test created.   lines.
rb.train created.   lines.
```

The files all appear in the folder; however, the majority of them are empty. `r5.test` is the only `.test` file with data and it contains the following data:

```
==> ratings.dat <==
71567::1984::1::912580553
71567::1985::1::912580553
71567::1986::1::912580553
71567::2012::3::912580722
71567::2028::5::912580344
71567::2107::1::912580553
71567::2126::2::912649143
71567::2294::5::912577968
71567::2338::2::912578016
71567::2384::2::912578173
```

Which is clearly not 20% of 10'000'000!

The only files that are about right are the`ra.train`, `ra.test`, rb.train`and`rb.test` - which are actually the only files I do not need!

I have no experience with Shell so therefore don't have a clue why this is occurring. I'm using Mac OS X and all the files were downloaded - I haven't altered any file structure.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. In fact, I tried it with Xubuntu and it worked flawlessly. So I opened `split_ratings.sh` and tried to figure out what was wrong with the script. Surprisingly, the problem was with the very first line. If on your terminal you run

```
$ wc -l ratings.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

it does not return a thing. The first command (in the left side of the pipe) counts the number of ratings that the file includes. The second, extracts the number from the string. If you run

```
$ wc -l ratings.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

you'll see it returns the number correctly.

So if you change this

```
RATINGS_COUNT=`wc -l ratings.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
```

to this

```
RATINGS_COUNT=`wc -l ratings.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
```

The script will now know how many ratings there are. Furthermore, if you apply the same change in lines 23, 24, 28, 29, 32 and 33, the script will output the number of lines (ratings) per generated file.

I hope it helps.